# Why does a Flask apps main thread block another thread from sending data?

Tags: python, flask, urllib2

I have a Flask app that spawns an internal thread to send data to another server periodically.

When the Flask app is initialized, the new thread is spawned:

```
sthread = Thread(target=DataPush, args=())
sthread.start()
```

Then inside sthread:

```
def DataPush():

    while True:

            # data contains the POST data

            method = "POST"
            handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler()
            opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
            request = urllib2.Request(server_url, data=data)
            request.add_header("Content-Type",'application/json')
            request.get_method = lambda: method
            try:
                connection = opener.open(request)
            except urllib2.HTTPError,e:
                connection = e

            if connection.code == 200:
                ndata = connection.read()
                print(ndata)
            else:
                print('error:' + str(connection.code))

        time.sleep(5)
```

The send is blocked (blocked at build_opener) apparently by the Flask apps main thread.  If I ctrl-C, the main flask app thread is killed, and suddenly the data send works (of course now the Flask app functionally is killed).

What is blocking the send?

Comment: Try to use a `process` and not a `thread` and see if that works

Comment: where are you creating the thread in your `app.py`?

Comment: right after the app is created...  app = Flask(\__name\__)

Comment: before the app.run()?   try  use app.run(threaded=True), before in default server (when you debug using werkzeug), there is only one thread.

Comment: I tried what you suggest and initialized the threads after the app.run.  Same problem.  The strange thing is that is seems to happen in opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler).  I looked at the source code here and its just straight initialization it seems, no comm stuff or locking, etc.  No obvious suspects.

Comment: Please remember that Python has a GIL so there is no real parallelism. You may want to use a worker queue like Celery. Also which version of Python are you using?